# pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: database error: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $set

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

In pymongo, I use `find_one()` to query and got a document. Then I use this doc to find_one(doc) again, I got this error.

> pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: database error: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $set

The document I got looks like this:

```
{
     u'_id': ObjectId('55768a989e7d5216a4a35e9a'),
     u'h': -5393879121411301345L,
     u'ts': Timestamp(1433739200, 23),
     u'o': {
         u'$set': {
             u'last_update_time': 1433739200.163728,
             u'value': 0,
             u'lv': 10,
             u'times': 30
         }
     },
     u'v': 2,
     u'ns': u'db.mycol',
     u'o2': {
         u'_id': 1234567
     },
     u'op': u'u'
}
```

What's more, If i want to use the returned document to query agian, what should I do to parse the document?

Comment: you should provide some condition in find_one not the whole document it this case you could use _id field

Comment: @Vignesh Kalai What if I don't know that there is a _id field, and I just want to find if this document in another collection? This really confused me.

Comment: John _id field is automatically generated when you insert a row in mongoDB so there should be no issue in querying for that .`are you still confused` and `do you need a code example`

Comment: @Vignesh Kalai I've got your idea. But same _id value cannot ensure that these two documents are the same, cause I need to compare documents in two collections. I want to check if doc1 in `db1.col` can also be found in `db2.col` or not.

Comment: _id column will always be unique no matter what is the case it is made that want in mongoDB

Comment: @Vignesh Kalai Actually, I have a db, and I backup it and restore it into another db. I want to check if the document on this db can be found in the backup db, including all fields. So _id column here does not help much.

Comment: Then the _id column will not match is there any other unique column in there

Comment: @Vignesh Kalai Not really. So I want to find docs by comparing every columns. But keys like "$set", is often treated as a field operator by mongo . But in oplog collection, "$set" is plain text, I think. So this is my problem.